# Count of a string in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]I have a  field carton no which is string type.The values are 1 and 2.
I gave summary as count for that in report footer .But it is showing 32 .But it should show 2 only.
Here the report having 32 records .I tried with changing string to number also

Comment: Post a picture of the report in preview mode.

Comment: How to post a picture here.Please tell

Comment: Edit your question, then click the image icon (the one to the right of `{}`.

Comment: I have 2 cartons but count i am getting as 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch your summarized field from `count` to `distinct count`.